# App crashes when using video and code that has worked with other video files

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, filepath

So I'm trying to play a video and the following code has worked for me with other video files so far but today I rendered out a new video (same rendering process as before so it should work - compression h.264 from AE and file is 14.7mb), dropped it in, change the name of the file and tried to run the app but it crashed and gave me a SIGBART error with this error: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' 
Now this sounds like it can't find the video file but it's in my sidebar with all my other video files that have worked with the same code and everything. I'm at a bit of a loss here... any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I'm pretty sure I've supplied all the code that you would need to see what's going on but if you need anything else, let me know and I'll update the post with it.

Thanks again!
Matt

```
NSURL *videoURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Comp 2" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerController *player2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: videoURL2 ];
UIImage  *thumbnail2 = [player2 thumbnailImageAtTime:13.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
player2.shouldAutoplay = NO;
player2.stop;
player2 = nil;
UIImageView *videoPicture2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:thumbnail2];
videoPicture2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
videoPicture2.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
videoPicture2.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
videoPicture2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
videoPicture2.layer.borderWidth = 1;
videoPicture2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor;
videoPicture2.frame = CGRectMake(145, 3, 82, 54);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the video was not added to the Target

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say the space in the filename might be the problem (since you're saying none of the code has changed aside from the video file, and since it's having trouble with the string).  Rename the file without the space, re-add it to your project, and try again.  See how it goes.

Failing that, make absolutely sure you've typed the filename correctly--case included.  I've had some issues before where I had a case-typo in my filenames and it ran fine on the simulator, but then when I put it on the device it crashed and I couldn't figure out why!

Comment: Yeah I tried changing the name before to a single word file... however I did it strait inside Xcode. I'll try doing it on the file on my desktop and go from there and let you know. The name of the file was correct though.

Comment: Yeah, I'd try that and see how it goes.  If not let me know and I'll try and think of something else, haha!  But I hope that solves it.